# Is there a specific name for arithmetic and operations on Probability Density Functions

Tags: probability, density-function

It is possible to add (independent) Probability Density Functions (resulting in convolution if I'm not mistaken), or to multiply, divide these… i.e. to perform **arithmetic on pdf**…

But has this specific type of calculation (this "category" ?) a **specific name** ? Is it just "arithmetic on Probability Density Functions" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [Stochastic Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization)

So long after having asked that question!

Answer (score 0):

The pdf's correspond to random variables; the usual terminology is that you're doing arithmetic on those random variables. In the example you mention, if you have rv's $X$ and $Y$, the convolution of their pdf's is the pdf of $X+Y$, so $X$ and $Y$ are what you're really adding.